# How to specify the action attribute to specific input buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I have a form in which I have 2 buttons which increase and decrease the values entered by the user. The form has an action attribute which sends all the data of the form to another PHP file. When I try to press the button, it just directs me to that page instead of increasing the value. I want the buttons to increase the value and when the submit button is clicked, the page should send all the data to the other PHP page.

Thanks In Advance!!!

> the buttons are images
>
> I have not included the PHP code

My HTML Code Snippet-

```
<form method="POST" action="cart.php">
  <div class="divStyle">
    <img src="img.png" height="100px" width="150px">
    <br>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['book1']; ?>
    <br><br>
    <?php echo $price1; ?>
    <br>
    <div class="inputStyle">
      <input type="image" src="minus.png" width="50px" height="50px" id="minus1" name="minus1"><input type="number" type="button" min="0" id="Q1" name="Q1" placeholder="Enter Quantity"><input type="image" src="plus.png" height="50px" width="50px" id="plus1" name="plus1">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="divStyle">
    <img src="img.png" height="100px" width="150px">
    <br>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['book2']; ?>
    <br><br>
    <?php echo $price2; ?>
    <br>
    <div class="inputStyle">
      <input type="image" src="minus.png" width="50px" height="50px" id="minus2" name="minus2"><input type="number" type="button" min="0" id="Q2" name="Q2" placeholder="Enter Quantity"><input type="image" src="plus.png" width="50px" height = "50px" id="plus2" name="plus2">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="divStyle">
    <img src="img.png" height="100px" width="150px">
    <br>
    <?php echo $_SESSION['book3']; ?>
    <br><br>
    <?php echo $price3; ?>
    <br>
    <div class="inputStyle">
      <input type="image" src="minus.png" width="50px" height="50px" id="minus3" name="minus3"><input type="number" type="button" min="0" id="Q3" name="Q3" placeholder="Enter Quantity"><input type="image" src="plus.png" width="50px" height = "50px" id="plus3" name="plus3">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
<input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1">
</form>
```

My Javascript Code-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#plus1').click( function() {
            var counter = $('#Q1').val();
            if (counter>= 0 && counter<5) {
            counter++ ;
            $('#Q1').val(counter);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#plus2').click( function() {
            var counter = $('#Q2').val();
            if (counter>= 0 && counter<5) {
            counter++ ;
            $('#Q2').val(counter);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#plus3').click( function() {
            var counter = $('#Q3').val();
            if (counter>= 0 && counter<5) {
            counter++ ;
            $('#Q3').val(counter);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#minus1').click( function() {
            var counter = $('#Q1').val();
            if(counter>0 && counter<6){
            counter-- ;
            $('#Q1').val(counter);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#minus2').click( function() {
            var counter = $('#Q2').val();
            if(counter>0 && counter<6){
            counter-- ;
            $('#Q2').val(counter);
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#minus3').click( function() {
            var counter = $('#Q3').val();
            if(counter>0 && counter<6){
            counter-- ;
            $('#Q3').val(counter);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Like This:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.cls-btn-plus-minus').click(function(){
  var cur_val = $(this).parent().find('.cls-q').val();
  cur_val = parseInt(cur_val)||0;
    var role = $(this).attr('role');

  if(role == 'plus'){
   if(cur_val>= 0 && cur_val<5) {
     cur_val++;
     $(this).parent().find('.cls-q').val(cur_val);
   }
  }

  if(role == 'minus'){
   if(cur_val> 0 && cur_val<6) {
     cur_val--;
     $(this).parent().find('.cls-q').val(cur_val);
   }
  }

 });
});
```

```css
.cls-btn-plus-minus{
   height:50px;
   width:50px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="cart.php">
  <div class="divStyle">
    <!--img src="img.png" height="100px" width="150px"-->
    <br>
    book1
    <br><br>
    price1
    <br>
    <div class="inputStyle">
      <img class="cls-btn-plus-minus" src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/64/000000/minus.png" role="minus">  
      <input type="number" class="cls-q" min="0" id="Q1" name="Q1" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
            <img class="cls-btn-plus-minus" src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/64/000000/plus.png" role="plus">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="divStyle">
    <!--img src="img.png" height="100px" width="150px"-->
    <br>
    book2
    <br><br>
    price2
    <br>
    <div class="inputStyle">
            <img class="cls-btn-plus-minus" src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/64/000000/minus.png" role="minus">  
      <input type="number" class="cls-q" min="0" id="Q2" name="Q2" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
      <img class="cls-btn-plus-minus" src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/64/000000/plus.png" role="plus">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="divStyle">
    <!--img src="img.png" height="100px" width="150px"-->
    <br>
    book
    <br><br>
    price3
    <br>
    <div class="inputStyle">
            <img class="cls-btn-plus-minus" src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/64/000000/minus.png" role="minus">  
      <input type="number" class="cls-q" min="0" id="Q3" name="Q3" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
      <img class="cls-btn-plus-minus" src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/64/000000/plus.png" role="plus">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
<input type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1" value="GO">
</form>
```

Comment: Changed buttons to images

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the form is being submitted early because your inputs are perhaps triggering the `form`s submit method.

We can simplify it a lot by using `button`s to wrap our increment and decrement actions (attach your `onclick` event handlers to these buttons), and use a single `input` to hold the value for each form field (your event handlers will be changing the values on these `input`s). You can disable or hide these `input`s to ensure changes to form data must pass through your event handlers and can't be entered directly into the `input`.

`button` elements will try and submit it's parent `form` element by default, so you need to use `type="button"` to prevent that.

Then, when your data is ready to submit, provide a single `button` or `input` with `type="submit"`.

This may also clean up the payload you receive in your php context as well, because the `form` action will try to wrap up every `input` and their values. It seems you're only interested in the `$price`, so let's make sure your form only encodes that data.

An example of the markup for each of your questions could look like this:

```html
<input id="my-input-1" type="number" value="0" disabled>
<button type="button" name="increment-my-input-1">
  <img src="/my-plus-button-image.png" />
</button>
<button type="button" name="decrement-my-input-1">
  <img src="/my-minus-button-image.png" />
</button>
```